# Can Directly run R snippet by an API call to OPENCPU?

Tags: r, code-snippets, opencpu

I am trying to use opencpu server to run R code via API calls. For R Markdown it works fine (as explained in opencpu example markdown app). I want to directly pass R code in to opencpu and get output. Is that possible?

Some thing like
http://localhost/ocpu/.../something
{"text" :"R code here"}

Comment: **For R Markdown it works fine**, what is the issue then? R Markdown will run R code, simply copy that code into  a script?

Comment: you can probably use `evalrcode <- function(rcode) eval(parse(text=rcode))`

Comment: @chinsoon12 can you please explain this?

Comment: iiuc u want to pass R code to ocpu server to be run. i guess u can create a R package, put this function in the R package, build the package. Start ocpu server. Then you can curl the function with the R code as input. e.g. `curl http://localhost/ocpu/library/newPackage/R/evalrcode -d "rcode='rnorm(1)'"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and well documented on the OpenCPU website, [here](https://www.opencpu.org/api.html)

> Argument formats for R function calls (HTTP POST only)
>
> > When calling a function, we need to pass arguments. OpenCPU accepts the following types of arguments:
> > Argument:plain R code --- Example: paste("useR", "2013"), mtcars

Answer (score 0):

I have found three ways to do this:

1. Post a `.r` file to OpenCPU at `../library/base/R/source`
2. Use `do.call`
3. Create your own R package and save on the server

I'll demo the first two methods:

**Method 1**

Post a file with parameter name `file` to  `../library/base/R/source`

Here is an example, in the image below you can see I am making a POST request using `localhost:8004/ocpu`, where I have OpenCPU monitoring port 8004 in a Docker container.

[image: Simulated post request]

Above, I inserted the file test.r. This is the contents of test.r:

```
g = "hello world"
x = "yoyoi"
```

So it is just a two line file. You can see OpenCPU returns the location parameter:
`Location: http://localhost:8004/ocpu/tmp/x0ec7fa2f50f510/`

If you go to that url, you will see the following:

```
console
files/DESCRIPTION
files/test.r
info
R/.val
R/source
source
```

`R/.val` is the output R object. So if you send get request to the link   `http://localhost:8004/ocpu/tmp/x0ec7fa2f50f510/R/.val`, you will see the output of running file `test.r`:

```
$value
[1] "yoyoi"

$visible
[1] FALSE
```

So basically, you can send a get request to the location url returned from your post request. Then you will get the last line of `test.r`

**Method 2**

You can use `do.call` from package base to execute a function:
[image: do.call example]

Above will return `onetwo`

**More Detailed Example:**
Here is a more detailed example. Since data persists on the OpenCPU server for a time, so you can use `do.call` in base R to execute a function on the output of `utils::read.csv`:

Step 1: read a file with read.csv, in this example I'm reading the cars dataset from [here](https://gist.github.com/noamross/e5d3e859aa0c794be10b)

[image: read csv]

Step 2: Apply `do.call` on the dataframe returned by `read.csv`:

[image: do.call on csv]

This outputs the first 6 rows of the dataframe:

```
                  X  mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
3        Datsun 710 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
6           Valiant 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

You can also return as JSON:

```
http://localhost:8004/ocpu/tmp/x0ecb9593c335da/R/.val/json
```

[image: JSON output]

I also just ran a test where I uploaded the cars data twice, which returned two different keys. I then used the `key::.val` notation with `do.call` to `rbind` the two dataframes together. So if you use that method you can even have an app where you upload 10 csv files and `rbind` them all together.